# How to add different image with pagination in ng-grid

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, ng-grid

I have a grid that displays images as values in one of its column using following code.

```
{
    field: 'TR',
    displayName: 'Trigger Redundancy',
    cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()"><span ng-cell-text><img src="http://goo.gl/aFomAA"></img></span></div>'   
}
```

Now I want few more alterations to my grid which I am unable to do,

1. Instead displaying one image as value for a column, I want five different images that should be shown on the basis of numeric value from 0-4.
2. I want to include bootstrap pagination to my grid.
3. After images are displayed, when I right click on it, it should provide me some functionality using which I could be able to change my image to some different image.
4. I want 1st column that should provide me a button, by clicking on it I should be able to display information of that row in some `textbox` below my grid.
5. I want to apply filtration on three of my columns such that I will provide user a `textbox` to search whatever he will type in that, that should be filtered from these three columns.

How can I achieve this? Possibly a working example?

I have a working demo [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7NkYmP0EMUS0agGZbWve?p=preview) of my grid

Comment: So you are asking 5 different questions in one.

Answer (score 0):

I have make chenges to show the images from 0 to 4 based on the data and even for the click function but i think to show some option you should avoid right click and you use left click and if you will make changes to the data source of gird it will automatically display the required value in the grid for showing different images.

Comment: can u pls share the code for displaying images based on data values?